# Unable to re-direct to page not found (React Hooks)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have been trying to create a Redirect from my details component to my NotFound component however I keep getting the below TypeError. I assume my if statement is in the wrong place?

```
Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
   8 | 
   9 | useEffect(() => {
  10 |   let tvShow = getGallery().find(gallery => gallery.id === tvShowId);
> 11 |   setDetailsText(tvShow.title);
     | ^  12 | }, [tvShowId]);
  13 | 
  14 | if(tvShowId === undefined) {
```

Tried to put my if statement before the useEffect hook and also within it.

```
export default function Details(props) {
const [detailsText, setDetailsText] = useState();
const tvShowId = props.match.params.tvShowUrl;

  useEffect(() => {
    let tvShow = getGallery().find(gallery => gallery.id === tvShowId);
    setDetailsText(tvShow.title);
  }, [tvShowId]);

  if(tvShowId === undefined) {
    return <Redirect to = '/NotFound' />
  } else {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{detailsText}</h1>
        <Link to="/">Return to Home Page</Link>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I want a Redirect if the wrong URL is input.

Comment: Post your `getGallery` function.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're almost there. You just need to avoid the error.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    let tvShow = getGallery().find(gallery => gallery.id === tvShowId);

    if (tvShow) {
        setDetailsText(tvShow.title);
    }
}, [tvShowId]);
```

The problems with `useEffect` in this case are:

1. The component holds extra state.
2. It renders twice per `props` change instead of once.
3. `tvShow` is delayed until the next render.

Try this instead:

```jsx
export default function Details(props) {
    const tvShowId = props.match.params.tvShowUrl;

    const tvShow = useMemo(
        () => getGallery().find(gallery => gallery.id === tvShowId),
        [tvShowId]
    );

    if (tvShowId === undefined) {
        return <Redirect to="/NotFound" />
    } else {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{tvShow}</h1>
                <Link to="/">Return to Home Page</Link>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is telling you that you are trying to access "title" but the object which you think it is attached to doesn't have any value. You could get past the error using :

```
if([name of the variable])
    [name of the variable].title;
```

So if your variable is called book :

```
if(book) // Checks if book is null
    console.log(book.title); // Only access the title if the book is not null
```